# drawing a line that follows your finger

Tags: actionscript-3, touch-event, starling-framework

I'm creating a game and i am trying to draw a line that is following my finger. I'm using the starling graphics axtension for this and that is working very nice and you can see how i do it below.

```
if (begin) {
    _startPoint = new Point(begin.globalX, begin.globalY);
    _line.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff, 1);
    addChild(_line);
} else if (moved) {
    var width:Number = MathUtils.DistanceBetweetnTwoPoints(_startPoint.x, _startPoint.y, moved.globalX, moved.globalY);
    _currentPoint = new Point(moved.globalX, moved.globalY);
    _line.graphics.clear();
    _line.graphics.moveTo(_startPoint.x, _startPoint.y);
    _line.graphics.lineTo(_currentPoint.x, _currentPoint.y);
} else if (end) {
    _line.graphics.clear();
    _endPoint = new Point(end.globalX, end.globalY);
    addBlock(_startPoint, _endPoint);
}
```

So what i want to do is the following. Atm moment it is just following my finger (draws a line from the startpoint to the currentpoint. But i want to enter a maximum width. Lets say 50. If it crosses the length of 50 it should just follow my finger rotationwise. So not getting any longer anymore but it does keep track of the direction of my finger and rotates towards it.

And a last thing (although i'm not sure if it's possible) is to let the line go from green to red, the closer it gets to its max length ( so entire line is green but it turns red the closer it gets to 50)

I have no idea how to achieve this sho it would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If points will be enough, then:

1. You calculate the distance between standpoint and touchpoint. If below your threshold, draw the full line.
2. If not, you calculate a proportion between your desired length and deltas of X and Y between the standpoint and touchpoint, you will receive an intermediate point that will be the end of your drawn line.
3. To select the color, either have a HSV or RGB interpolation between green and red. A stupid example of `uint(255*lineLength/50)*0x10000+uint(255*(1.0-lineLength/50))*0x100` will do for some time. `lineLength` in here ranges from 0 to 50.0.

After you calculate all of this, you're set to draw a line as you did.

And a nitpick: the line "width" is named "thickness", which is 1 in your example (is set in `lineStyle` along with the color).

Comment: +1. Was typing up almost exactly this, but your colour operation is neater. @vincent, note you'll need to apply the same proportional scaling to your `_endPoint`.

Comment: And how would you calculate that point? Very sorry, math isnt my strongest point :(

Comment: Well, learning maths will help you a great deal once you'll start to get thick into programming :) First, you calculate the part of the line you have to draw: `var part:Number=50.0/lineLength;` Then you calculate X&Y as this: `newX=_startpoint.x+(_endpoint.x-_startpoint.x)*part;` (for Y switch `.x` for `.y`).